# Can all monster types be captured?

Tags: world-of-final-fantasy

This is in regards to the Imprism system that is used to capture monsters that you battle.

Generally I find that when you lower an enemies health down they will eventually show the animation that indicates they can be captured and the Imprism action becomes available on them.

However, I have bumped into a couple of monsters that I just can't get them into that state no matter how low their health. In one case the health bar was so low I couldn't actually see any health in the bar (it looked completely empty, like 1hp or something). I am not sure the name of this particular creature but it was a small bat type.

So, the questions is, are there some monsters that just cannot be captured?

Or is this a case where I don't understand the system, and lowering health isn't the only method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll convert my huge comment into an answer.

**Can all monsters be imprismed?**
In the Twin's Room, the mirage manual lists the total mirages (21 pages of 10 per page, plus 4, totalling 214), and there are achievements for various levels of your mirage collection. So I would image that not every single mirage in the game is imprisamable.

[List of mirages](http://www.rpgsite.net/feature/5039-world-of-final-fantasy-mirage-guide-mirage-list-prismtunity-abilities-more-part-1)

**How to imprism**
There are three things that you need to be able to imprism a mirage.

Firstly you'll need a matching prism, which you'll be given automatically by Enna Kros when you first encounter a new mirage. You can earn more in the mirages Mirage Board, by spending AP.

Secondly you'll need to use Libra on the mirage to see what it's prismunity condition is. There are lots of different ones, from physical dmg, elemental dmg, to applying conditions, and even healing the mirage. Prismunities have multiple levels, so you might need to do the action more than once. The glowing ring will get bigger on each level, the bigger the ring, the easier it is to imprism the mirage.

The last thing is that the enemy needs to be imprismable, and not have an existing master; Libra should tell you this.

If you've met all these conditions, using the 'Standard' battle menu, `L1` in battle, you can see mirages which you can imprism by looking at the targeting window. Mirages which you have a prism for and can be imprismed will show a small gold octagon icon next to them.

It's worth noting that Libra data is saved, so if you've encountered a mirage previously, and cast Libra, you can press `options` to see it's data, and thus it's prismunity condition. Also worth noting that you must topple stacks before being able to imprism a mirage.

Answer (score 2):

I have only played the demo so far so this may or  may not be accurate but it seemed to show that all monsters have a condition that needs to be met to trigger the imprism state (I think you might also need a relevant kind of crystal as well, I remember some in my inventory).  For most it seemed that damage was the trigger but some needed fire or water damage specifically, using Libra revealed what needed to be done to get a chance at inducing that state

Comment: Cheers, that sounds useful. I will check out the Libra info but if it does state specific requirements then I expect that is what I am missing.